# Using list for multi projects

Tags: premake

I use premake5 version 5.0.0-alpha11 for multi projects. Each project is a independent with each others.
Currently, my premake5.lua as below

```
-- The windowed app
```

`project "1.DepthTest"`

```
kind "ConsoleApp"

filter { "system:Windows" }
files "Projects/1.DepthTest/**"

filter { "system:windows" }
    links { "OpenGL32" }

filter { "system:not windows" }
    links { "GL" }
```

`project "2.StencilTest"`

```
kind "ConsoleApp"

filter { "system:Windows" }
files "Projects/2.StencilTest/**"
filter { "system:windows" }
    links { "OpenGL32" }

filter { "system:not windows" }
    links { "GL" }
```

And I have around 20 projects like this. Do you have any idea how to make it sorter as using a list same as cmake ? Such as

```
projectsList {'1.DepthTest','2.StencilTest'}
func GenerateProject(projectList[i])
```

**Update**
Finally, I know how to do with my requirement

```
function GenerateProject(s)
print(s)
project (s)
    kind "ConsoleApp"

    files {
    './' .. s .. '/**.*',
  }
end

for key, value in ipairs(projectsList) do
    GenerateProject(value)
end
```

Also the projects is generated without structure, I found the question about vpaths in [Hide common parent folders of project files in Premake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192274/hide-common-parent-folders-of-project-files-in-premake)
But I still not clear how to do it.

Many thanks,
Seal

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of structure you are trying to create.

Comment: Hi @starkos ,  thank you for reply. Finally, i can create the project with structure. It similar like this [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/eyn0rGQUjJcTlUnt1)

Comment: Add your standard project structure commands like: `vpaths { ["Source"]={path.join("Projects",s,"**.c*")}, ["Headers"]={path.join("Projects",s,"**.h*")} }` inside the `project(s)` block in your function.

Comment: Hi @JesseChisholm, Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it still not generated with the structure I want ...